# docker-compose volume wrong permission root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, volume

I'm trying to get wordpress working with docker but I have a lot a problem with the `/wp-content/uploads` folder, I use docker-compose and swarm.

this is part of the docker-compose:

```
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxx/xxx
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
    env_file:
      - wp.env
    networks:
      - sv-frontend
      - sv-backend
```

and this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . .

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/* && \
    ls -l  /var/www/html/wp-content/
```

the problem is that `/wp-content/uploads` has root:root as permission, what I'm doing wrong?

To deploy the app I use `docker stack deploy.....` the image is created using the gitlab pipeline but I don't think is a gitlab problem

Comment: I just built your Dockerfile and upload has no root permission: **drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug  3 02:55 uploads** has **www-data** owner as expected

Comment: not sure how it is working for you and not for me....anyway I found the error on my setup, the upload folder on my server it was set as the current user, changing the permission to www-data on the folder on my server fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

> You need to add command to set ownership because wordpress_data not
>   mounted when you call command from dockerfile

Try this way

```
docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh then chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

You can change ownership of mounted volume after container run, just need to run one time (i'm not sure ownership will revert back each times container restarted but this worth to try).

Comment: mmm doing this the container wont start, keep restarting

Comment: then simple way will do. docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh then chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads